# how to fix the error AttributeError: 'Country' object has no attribute 'City_set' . in django

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

i have 3 dependent dropdownlists country city road.

where country is pre-populated from the database  and based on the selection of the first the second will display the related cities.

the problem is that once the user select from the first dropdownlist the system display the below error :

> all_cities = selected_country.City_set.all() AttributeError:
>   'Country' object has no attribute 'City_set'

i do not know how to fix this error.

## models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def __str__(self):
        # return'id : {0} MouhafazatID :{1} Name :{2}'.format(self.id,self.MouhafazatID,self.name)
        return str(self.name)

class Road(models.Model):
    Vil = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city= models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    country= models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Vil)
```

## home2.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
             $('select#selectcountries').change(function () {
                 var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                 var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                 var country_name   = optionSelected.text();


                 data = {'cnt' : country_name };
                 alert(country_name);
                 $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:'/getdetails',
                     // data:JSON.stringify(data),
                     data:data,
                     success:function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#selectcities option").remove();
                        for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            $("#selectcities").append('<option>'+ result[i].name +'</option>');
                        };
                      },
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="selectcountries" id="selectcountries">
        {% for item in countries %}
            <option val="{{ item.name }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>    
        {% endfor %}
        </select>   


        <select name ="selectcities" id="selectcities">


        </select>       

        <select name ="selectroads" id="selectroads">


        </select>



    </body>
</html>
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse
from testapp.models import *

import json as simplejson



def home2(request):
    countries = Country.objects.all()
    print("countries =", countries)
    return render(request, 'home2.html',{'countries': countries})



def getdetails(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        country_name = request.GET.get('cnt', None) 
        print ("ajax country_name ", country_name)

        result_set = []
        all_cities = []

        answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
        print('answer = ' ,answer)
        selected_country = Country.objects.get(name=answer)
        print ("selected country name ", selected_country)

        all_cities = selected_country.City_set.all()
        print("cities are: " , all_cities)
        for city in all_cities:
            print ("city name", city.name)
            result_set.append({'name': city.name})

        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result_set),content_type='application/json')
        # return JsonResponse(result_set,status = 200)

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

as you see i am passing the data in json format.

but the function in **views.py** execute until this line

```
print ("selected country name ", selected_country)
```

with correct value.

and then it display the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing reverse foreign key relations, always use lower cases when mentioning the related model. It is

```
all_cities = selected_country.city_set.all()
```

For better readability, use the `related_name` attribute when declaring the foreign key field. Example:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cities')
```

By adding the above `related_name` attribute, you can access the cities as follows:

```
all_cities = selected_country.cities.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `City_set` with `city_set` as lower cases are used.